# How to manage component rendering when there are several small, repeatable sub-components in React/Flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

The Flux pattern of having React components listen for updates to a central store is great, but seems to present an issue when you have numerous small, composable parts all on the same page requiring re-renders from a single store.  On first inspection, it looks like the developer is required to tradeoff between two choices: creating a parent component which manages state and the rendering responsibilities of these smaller, repeatable components vs having each component manage its own resources, but hold a large number event handlers open (one for each repeated component).

To illustrate, my existing structure looks something like this:

- I have an `EventList` component that contains a list of (potentially hundreds of) `Event` components to render as children.
- The `Event` component includes an `AuthenticatedImage` as a child component when rendering.
- The `AuthenticatedImage` component listens to changes on the `TokenStore` and re-renders when an update occurs (a new token, re-render with that token).

`TokenStore` updates very rarely, but we definitely want to re-render all `AuthenticatedImage` components when this happens.

Here's the dilemma: If I have each `AuthenticatedImage` listen for changes to the `TokenStore`, Javascript starts complaining that we have a large number of open event handlers to the same event (that is, potentially hundreds of components all listening to the same event).  In contrast, I could have the parent `EventList` component listen for updates to `TokenStore`, but then `EventList` starts owning the responsibilities of `AuthenticatedImage`, and `AuthenticatedImage` loses its portability.

Given these thoughts, what is the correct way to ensure that numerous instances of a component are re-rendered on a store change, without consuming exorbitant amounts of memory and angering the Javascript Gods, while ensuring code is kept clean and portable?

Comment: Take a look at [container components](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005) and [smart and dumb components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0); you are probably asking your `AuthenticatedImage` components to do more that they should.

Answer (score 0):

In flux-thinking, it sounds like your `AuthenticatedImage` should be a pure component = not having state (nor listeners) and only respond to props being passed down from parent. It is generally advised to try and keep state as high up in your component-hierarchy as possible.

Having the token-fetch in a component and in its state would make sense if only one of the images needs to respond to the new token. But this is not the case I understand.

By centralising token-fetching, `AuthenticatedImage` would still be quite portable. It only loses its responsibility to fetch the token, but this is probably a good idea anyway: there are evidently many components that need the same token, so centralising token fetching is a logical step. Especially if components other than your `AuthenticatedImage` respond to a token.

It also keeps your data stores and components aligned: centralised storing of token = centralised fetching of token. Putting it in the `AuthenticatedImage` component would make sense if you would also store each token separately with each image instance.

What you get in return is that any change in token-fetching logic needs to be processed only once, and not in each component-class that uses the token.